# How to add data in any selected column or row in a datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, row, cell

Im tasked to make a schedule form and with that I have to add multiple text in one column or data in each assigned day.

The problem I have is that it can only add in one row for multiple columns.

What I need to do is to add data in multiple rows for each column.

Here is a part of the code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //dgv1.Rows.Add(1);
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Monday")
        {

            DataGridViewRow row = dgv1.Rows[rowcount];
            row.Height = 60;

            grpclassname = textBox1.Text;
            txtinst = cmbInstructor.Text;
            txtdesc = textBox3.Text;
            txtFull = grpclassname + "\n" + txtinst + "\n" + txtdesc;

            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value = 
                   tp1.Value.ToShortTimeString() + " - " + tp2.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[1].Value = txtFull;

            //rowcount++;
            //dgv1.Rows.Add(1);
        }

        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Tuesday")
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgv1.Rows[rowcount];
            row.Height = 60;

            grpclassname = textBox1.Text;
            txtinst = cmbInstructor.Text;
            txtdesc = textBox3.Text;
            txtFull = grpclassname + "\n" + txtinst + "\n" + txtdesc;

            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value = 
                   tp1.Value.ToShortTimeString() + " - " + tp2.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[2].Value = txtFull;

            //rowcount++;
        }

        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Wednesday")
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgv1.Rows[rowcount];
            row.Height = 60;

            grpclassname = textBox1.Text;
            txtinst = cmbInstructor.Text;
            txtdesc = textBox3.Text;
            txtFull = grpclassname + "\n" + txtinst + "\n" + txtdesc;

            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value = 
                   tp1.Value.ToShortTimeString() + " - " + tp2.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            dgv1.Rows[rowcount].Cells[3].Value = txtFull;

            //rowcount++;
        }
```

Comment: Seems like you want to merge rows?

Comment: I'not sure I have understood correctly your question but try to modify "\n" with Environment.NewLine

Comment: i need to input data in more than one row...i cant seem to add another row ... yes i guess merging rows is what i would like to do

Comment: I can't understand what you need I'm afraid but I can see that the code so far is repetitive. Somehow the user picks a day from a combobox. What else shall the user do and what shall be the result?

Comment: after picking a day from the comboBox the data placed inside the textboxes will be placed in the appropriate columns that correspond to the chosen day